# MVC model for login validation in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, authentication

I am new to Java but eager to learn. I am attempting to use an MVC model with the Users.java class controlling my servlets. I feel like am I close to getting this to work but something must be off. Ideally, after pressing submit the username and password would be checked against the users.properties file if there is a match the user would be redirected to the customer home page. If no match, the user is redirected to the registration page. After entering the registration info, the info would be stored to the users.properties file and the user redirected to the homepage.

Login.jsp

```
 <form action=Login method="post">

 User Name: <input type=text name=userName><br>
 Password: <input type=password name=password><br>
  <input type=submit value=Login onClick="validate(this.form)"> <br> 
</form>
```

With the associated servlet java file
Login.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse       
   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    /* Following two statements are used to obtain the absolute path 
       of the users.properies file from its relative path. */
    ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
    String propFilePath = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/users.properties");

    Users aUser = new Users(userName, password);
    if (aUser.validateUser(aUser,propFilePath)) {
        response.sendRedirect("CustomerHomePage.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("Registration.jsp");
    }
 }
```

So if the user is redirected, it goes to a page quite similar to the login.jsp. The register.java is also quite similar to the login.java. Main difference is below.

register.java servlet

```
// Registration via the Users object
Users aUser = new Users(userName, password);

// Register the Users object
aUser.registerUser(aUser, propFilePath);
    response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
```

Finally, the controller. Likely this is where I went wrong but I'm so new to this I figured I could have went wrong anywhere.

```
public class Users {

private String userName;
private String password;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public Users(String userName, String password) {
    super();
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}

public void registerUser(Users aUser, String propFilePath) {

    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(propFilePath);
        p.load(fis);
        p.setProperty(aUser.getUserName(), aUser.getPassword());
        p.store(new FileOutputStream(propFilePath), null);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(fis!=null) {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 }

 public boolean validateUser(Users aUser, String propFilePath){
    boolean success = true;
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(propFilePath);

        p.load(fis);

        // Check whether the username exists or not
        if(!p.containsKey(aUser.getUserName())) {           
            // Link-redirection
            success = false;
        } else { // Check whether the password matches or not
            String pword = p.getProperty(aUser.getUserName());  
            if(!pword.equals(aUser.getPassword())) {
                success = true; // Link-redirection
            } else {
                success = false; // Link-redirection
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    } finally {
            if(fis!=null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }   

  }
    return success;
 }
}
```

Edit: I should also add that I have this code at the bottom of the servlet

I do have this code as well I should have added

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  
  response) throws ServletException, IOException { doGet(request, response);
 }
```

So the form from the login page will send you to the registration page, when I enter in the registration info it goes back to log in like it should. But, when I enter in the login info again, it won't go to the homepage.

Edit2:
Found my mistake. Had to switch around the boolean logic of my validateUsers method. Rookie mistake. :(

New Code:

```
  else { // Check whether the password matches or not
            String pword = p.getProperty(aUser.getUserName());  
            if(!pword.equals(aUser.getPassword())) {
                success = flase; // Link-redirection
            } else {
                success = true; // Link-redirection
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your form is `method="post"` but your servlet is `doGet` - is this your problem?  Please state what your problem is

Comment: Sorry. The problem is that I can't seem to go from the login.jsp to the customerhome page. I am stuck in a loop going from the login.jsp to the registration.jsp. Not sure if it is that my register.java is not storing the login info or that there is something wrong with my login validation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be anything but looking at your code, your form you are using **post** this is correct as you are posting data to server and also you don't want it visible in your url but then you are handling it using **doGet** in your servlet put your code **doPost**.

For your case:

- doGet should return the requested page
- doPost should do the process
  and return result or as for your case take user to registration/homepage

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry I should have added the doPost method. I do call the doGet method in doPost. I've tried putting everything into doPost and still no luck. Not sure if my registration info is being saved to the users.properties file or how to debug for that.

Comment: That's great we have progress, are you familiar with forward, include and send redirect? as you mentioned "I am stuck in a loop going from the login.jsp to the registration.jsp". As per your code above looks ok but if your logic is longer you might want to call return; within a block of redirect to stop/end execution. "Not sure if my registration info is being saved to the users.properties file or how to debug" simply view your user.properties is there data? or add breakpoints or logger within a block to see if execution took place. Anything just update your question with the log info, cheers.

Comment: Welp. I'm an idiot. All I had to do was switch around some boolean statements. or remove the ! from the !pword.equals statement of the validateUsers method. Thank you for your help. Printing things to the console to debug helped a lot.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help, if you could accept my answer and or comment would be helpful and useful to others that might be in the same circumstances in future. Cheers.